# how verify if a method was called in a concrete class at unit test in swift

Tags: swift, unit-testing

I have this scenario:

```
class X {
    init(y: ProtocolA)

    func foo(){
        if(y.isSomething()){
            methodA()
        } else {
            methodB()
        }
    }

    func methodA(){
        // any 
    }

    func methodB(){
        // any
    }

}

class Y : ProtocolA {

    func isSomething(): Bool { return true OR false }

}
```

i wanna test **class X**,

i will mock **ProtocolA** to return in **isSomething()** method true or false in two different test to know if **methodA** or **methodB** was called.

What the best strategy to solve this?

ps: with mockito, using a **Spy** with **verify** this is very easy, but with Swift this is very painful

edit:

well, i do this:

first, the parts:

```
class X { init(y: Y) }
protocol Y { func isSomething() -> Bool }
```

now, the struct for test: **mock** and **spy object**

```
typealias VerifyMethodAssert = (count: Int, parameters: [Any]?, returnn: Any?)
```

**Configurable Mock for Dependency**

```
class YMock : Y {


        init(configure: Bool)
        func isSomething{ return configure }

    }
```

Spy for concrete class

```
class XSpy : X {

    private let y: Y

    var verify: [String: VerifyMethodAssert] = [
        "methodA()": (count: 0, parameters: nil, returnn: nil)
        "methodB()": (count: 0, parameters: nil, returnn: nil)
    ]

    var nothing: [String: Bool] = [
        "methodA()": false
        "methodB()": false
    ]

    init(y: Y, verify: [String: VerifyMethodAssert]?, nothing: [String: Bool]?)

    func methodA(){
        verify["\(#function)"] = (count: verify["\(#function)"]!.count + 1, parameters: nil, 
            returnn: nothing["\(#function)"]! ? nil : super.methodA())
    }

    func methodB(doNothing: Bool = false){
        verify["\(#function)"] = (count: verify["\(#function)"]!.count + 1, parameters: nil, 
            returnn: nothing["\(#function)"]! ? nil : super.methodB())
    }

}
```

and test:

```
class XTest : QuickSpec {

    override func spec(){
        describe("a position view model"){

            it("test 1"){
                let y = Y(configure: true)
                let x = XSpy(y: y)

                x.foo()

                expect(1).to(x.verify["methodA()"].count)
                expect(0).to(x.verify["methodB()"].count)
            }

            it("test 2"){
                let y = Y(configure: true)
                let x = XSpy(y: y)

                x.foo()

                expect(0).to(x.verify["methodA()"].count)
                expect(1).to(x.verify["methodB()"].count)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box way as far as I know. 
One way to do it is to check a counter:

```
class X {

    var countA: Int = 0
    var countB: Int = 0

    init(y: ProtocolA)

    func foo(){
        if(y.isSomething()){
            methodA()
        } else {
            methodB()
        }
    }

    func methodA(){
        countA += 1
        // any 

    }

    func methodB(){
        countB += 1
        // any
    }

}
```

This approach is also suggested [here](https://qualitycoding.org/swift-mock-objects/).

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case you can subclass `X` and use an associated object to hold invocation counts, you can generalize this if you see yourself using it again and again:

```
final class TestX: X {

    private struct AssociatedKeys {
        static var invocations = "\(String(describing: type(of: TestX.self)))-invocations"
    }

    func invocations(for method: String) -> Int {
        return invocations[method] ?? 0
    }

    private var invocations: [String: Int] {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.invocations) as? [String: Int] ?? [:]
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject( self, &AssociatedKeys.invocations, newValue as NSDictionary, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }

    override func methodA(){
        super.methodA()
        invocations["methodA"] = (invocations["methodA"] ?? 0) + 1
    }

    override func methodB(){
        super.methodB()
        invocations["methodB"] = (invocations["methodB"] ?? 0) + 1
    }
}

let x = TestX(y: Y())
x.invocations(for: "methodA") //0
x.foo()
x.invocations(for: "methodA") //1
```